Get the difference between Successive timestamps KQL
I have a dataset as below
[
env_seqNum:int, env_tim:datetime, message:string, scenario: string, subscenario: string, requestId: string
1,2024-05-30T09:33:29.00Z, StartingOperation getToken XXX, ScenarioA, SubscenarioA, abcd-fghf,
2,2024-05-30T09:33:35.00Z, FinishingOperation getToken XXX, ScenarioA, SubscenarioA, abcd-fghf,
15,2024-05-30T09:33:55.00Z, StartingOperation getToken XXX, ScenarioA, SubscenarioA, abcd-fghf,
19,2024-05-30T09:33:58.00Z, FinishingOperation getToken XXX, ScenarioA, SubscenarioA, abcd-fghf,
]

As you can see, I have a token acquire operation thats done twice in same request for doing two API calls.
Now, I want to know the cumulative time thats taken for this token acquistion operation per request.
I cannot just do a diff of first and last row as it gives me a diff of 29 secs while in reality both token acquire operations took 9s (6 & 3)
How do I get this working in KQL?
I am wondering how can we leverage the env_seqNum column to perform this operation as its unique to every row int he logs or Is there a better way?

Expected is something like
requestId,Operation,subScenario, TimeTaken
abcd-fghf,TokenAcquired,SubScenario, 9 (6+3)

Table looks like below:

To get cumulative duration you can use below KQL query:
let Rith = datatable (
    ri_env_seqNum:int, 
    ri_env_tim:datetime, 
    ri_message:string, 
    ri_scenario:string, 
    ri_subscenario:string, 
    ri_requestId:string
) [
    1, datetime(2024-05-30T09:33:29.00Z), "StartingOperation getToken XXX", "ScenarioA", "SubscenarioA", "abcd-fghf",
    2, datetime(2024-05-30T09:33:35.00Z), "FinishingOperation getToken XXX", "ScenarioA", "SubscenarioA", "abcd-fghf",
    15, datetime(2024-05-30T09:33:55.00Z), "StartingOperation getToken XXX", "ScenarioA", "SubscenarioA", "abcd-fghf",
    19, datetime(2024-05-30T09:33:58.00Z), "FinishingOperation getToken XXX", "ScenarioA", "SubscenarioA", "abcd-fghf"
];
let ri_so_OP = Rith
    | where ri_message startswith "StartingOperation getToken"
    | project ri_requestId, start_seqNum = ri_env_seqNum, start_time = ri_env_tim;
let ri_fo_OP = Rith
    | where ri_message startswith "FinishingOperation getToken"
    | project ri_requestId, ri_finish_seqNum = ri_env_seqNum, finish_time = ri_env_tim;
let ri_pa_OP = ri_so_OP
    | join kind=inner (ri_fo_OP) on ri_requestId
    | where ri_finish_seqNum > start_seqNum
    | summarize ri_min_finish_seqNum = min(ri_finish_seqNum) by ri_requestId, start_seqNum, start_time
    | project ri_requestId, start_seqNum, start_time, ri_min_finish_seqNum;
ri_pa_OP
| join kind=inner (ri_fo_OP) on $left.ri_requestId == $right.ri_requestId and $left.ri_min_finish_seqNum == $right.ri_finish_seqNum
| project ri_requestId, start_time, finish_time, duration = datetime_diff('second', finish_time, start_time)
| summarize rith_cumula_duration = sum(duration) by ri_requestId
| project ri_requestId, rith_cumula_duration

Output:

Fiddle.

Hey  @RithwikBojja, I am newbie and trying to get my hands dirty with KQL. How do we build such advanced skills in KQL? Any suggestions for me?

Try and try and check some docs on it.
